Calva not showing Leiningen project type as option
I'm fairly new to Clojure, and VS code is my preferred IDE. I want to do REPL-driven development but one issue I'm running into is when attempting to "jack-in" using the Calva extension for VS code, leiningen is not listed as a project type I can select-- I only see Babashka, nbb, and joyride.
Perhaps I've missed a preceding step? I do have leiningen properly installed on my machine, as lein commands work in the default Mac terminal.
I opened a .clj file from my project in VS Code, navigated to the command palette and selected the option "Start project with REPL and connect." The immediate next option does not display leiningen as an optional project type, which it should be doing.
I've already uninstalled and reinstalled the extension, as well as halting any REPLs I started via my Mac terminal before attempting to start one via VS Code.

Does your project have a properly composed project.clj file at its root?

Yes! It is a template project.

There needs to be a Leiningen project in the active folder for Calva to list Leiningen as a project type you can start/jack-in to. See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#creating-a-project for how to create the project. TL;DR: lein new app foo, where foo is the name/top namespace of your project.

This has already been done!

The issue was simply having just a single project folder active! All good now.
